# TDCH via Spark fails

Tags: apache-spark, apache-nifi

I'm trying to execute a TDCH job via Spark and facing an issue where it fails throwing below error:
`<console>:1: error: ';' expected but double literal found`

Below is my TDCH statement: 
`hadoop jar teradata-connector-1.5.3.jar com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorExportTool -url jdbc:teradata://DWTST.trainfits.com/DATABASE=testDB -username testUser -jobtype hdfs -sourcepaths '/path/to/source/file' -separator , -nummappers 2 -targettable testTable -password test123`

The TDCH statement runs fine from the console without any issue. When I create a file of this command and pass it via spark-shell, it doesn't executes.

Below command to execute:
`spark2-shell -i tdchCommand.scala`

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess I'm doing something wrong here; still to figure out. I'm trying to execute a non-spark statement on spark shell. Is that the issue?

Comment: Where exactly NiFi comes here? Are you using any NiFi processor like `ExecuteScript` to execute the Spark job?

Comment: Ohh yes. Sorry, I forgot to include the NiFi part. Yes, I'm using `ExecuteScript` processor and Groovy to create scripts.

Comment: Can you share the error trace from `nifi-app.log`?